# CakePHP AuthLogin always false

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, controller

I have a CakePHP application, on which users can register, following constellation:

```
Table `users`
  Fields
    id
    token
    token_expires
    username
    email
    password
    role_id
    confirmed
    login_count
    created
    modified

Table `profiles`
  Fields
    id
    user_id
    birthdate
    phone
    mobile
    website
    created
    modified
```

I set the relation in the Model as following:

```
User.php:
public $hasOne = array(
    'Profile' => array(
        'className' => 'Profile',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

Profile.php:
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Now **the problem**:
As soon as the user registers, an entry in the table `users` is created. After the first login, the user has to create a `profiles` entry.

Login is possible, as long as the user doesn't have a `profiles` entry. As soon as the user has a profile, the login doesn't work anymore. Here my UsersController.php:

```
public function login() {
    // Delete session
    $this->Auth->logout();

    // invalidate data
    // ...

    if($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        return $this->Session->setFlash('User & password combination not valid');
    }
}
```

As said: If the user has no profile, login is possible. If the user has a profile, the login won't work.
I'm now for hours on this problem and can't find a solution. The worst thing about this, I can't debug anything, because `debug($this->Auth->login());` is always false.

If you also don't know the solution; how can I debug the Auth process properly?
Or can I pass a custom array to `$this->Auth->login()` instead of the automatic `$this->request->data['User']`?

Kind regards

Comment: You are going to need to provide more code. Specifically, I need to see where you are loading the auth component in the controller.

Comment: Hi @chrisShick, sorry for my delayed answer. My AppController.php is on following link: https://jsfiddle.net/9jubhrqp/2/

Comment: What version of cake are you using?

Comment: Version 2.4.1, does it matter? oO